# Creating modal on page load with cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux, react-redux, material-ui

I am trying to figure out a way to load a modal when the user visits the website, it automatically load with a modal with discount sign up...I'm not quiet sure or familiar with redux actions to set this. Anyone have clue where to start?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a suitable question for SO. I'd recommend checking out the Reactiflux community for more casual questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `material-ui's modal view`: https://material-ui.com/components/modal/

And use `useEffect` hook of React(in index.js): https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

You can pass empty array as second argument of useEffect so that the function won't fire up every time component re-renders like below,

```
function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadModalView();
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello World!</div>;
}
```